# How do I robustly tilt a strength-1 wall?

Tags: building, moc, snot

#### Background

I am still working on my model of a ride-on mower, which has a seat that looks like this:

[image: Original]

As you can see, the seat is mounted onto an inclined surface, which I realised to my satisfaction and which causes the seating area of the seat to be inclined as well. However, this means if I build the back of the seat in a rectangular manner, it will be inclined forwards, which is unrealistic (and uncomfortable for the driver). Therefore I need to tilt it backwards.

#### Goal

I have a 6×1 wall mounted onto one side of a regular 6×n plate and want to tilt it by at least 10° and at most 40°. With regular hinges, this looks like this:

[image: Attempt]
[image: Attempt from another point of view]

However, if I use regular hinges, the result is not very robust and the wall falls down easily. I am therefore looking for a more robust solution.

Some specifications:

- Whatever is needed to tilt the wall may not extend below the plate. (I need that place for something else, namely the complicated mounting.)
- Whatever is needed to tilt the wall may extend somewhat forward (onto the plate) on the sides (resembling the above seat) but not backwards.
- All components should be available in black. (I used red in the examples for better visibility.)
- The inclination may begin somewhat above the plate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best solution so far are minifigure legs (which are pretty robust on their own) combined with a clip tile to hold the wall in place:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I propose a slightly different solution for the chair: Use Technic bricks.

[image]

In this picture I have used [32526 Technic 5x3 bent 90](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32526&name=Technic,%20Liftarm%203%20x%205%20L-Shape%20Thick&category=%5BTechnic,%20Liftarm%5D#T=C) pieces, with [43857 Technic Beam 2](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43857&name=Technic,%20Liftarm%201%20x%202%20Thick&category=%5BTechnic,%20Liftarm%5D#T=C) and [32523 Technic Beam 3](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32523#T=C) pieces to make the chair uniform. You can make one or two attachment points to ground by either utilizing [64276 Technic Beam 2 Liftarm with Straight Ball Joint](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64276#T=C) as in the picture below, or using [3651 Technic Axle and Pin Connector](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3651&name=Technic,%20Axle%20and%20Pin%20Connector&category=%5BTechnic,%20Connector%5D#T=C) with a friction pin instead. For optimal reproduction of the original chair, you might want to use two of these supports in your model (my image only shows one).

Then, tilt the chair lightly back on the ball joint or connector, and use [4274 Technic Pin 1/2](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4274&name=Technic,%20Pin%201/2&category=%5BTechnic,%20Pin%5D#T=C) together with 1x4 and 1x3 tiles to create horizontal and vertical armrests just like on the chair in your picture. You could even combine the new 1x2 tile with rounded edge with a 1x2 or 1x1 tile, mounted on a 1x3 or 1x2 plate, to create a curved top and bottom edge. Note that in the picture above I have offset the vertical tile by half a stud to make it fit more nicely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have already devised a complicated mounting of that seat, which I am quite satisfied with (with shock absorbers and the option to half-unmount the seat and turn it forward – all of which you can do with the original seat). This mounting is what happens under the 6×n plate in my setup and requires that the seat is inclined forwards (because it is mounted on something which already has to be inclined).

Comment: You could still use the above design, by making a rotating joint at the front instead of at the back using the aforementioned 3651 Technic Axle and Pin Connector.